# Print artifact in Chrome for SVG

Tags: google-chrome, svg

The following simple SVG example draws an ugly line. When this is opened in Chrome 65 or Chromium 67, everything appears as expected. But when the print preview is opened, in addition to the red ugly line, there is a black line drawn right down the center of the ugly red line. My apologies if you think the red line is actually quite beautiful, but does anyone know what on earth Chrome is doing this for? I really don't want my ugly line ruined.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    .grid {
       stroke: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
       stroke-width: 15px;
       stroke-dasharray: 1,5;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="1000" height="700" viewBox="0 0 1000 700" style="width: 1000; height: 700;">
       <line x1="100" x2="100" y1="15" y2="665" class="grid"></line>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ignore the scaling differences. The black line in the center of the print version is undesirable.

[image: Screen version]
[image: Print preview, print version]

Comment: Presumably a bug that should be reported to Chrome's bugtracker.

Comment: Try setting `stroke-dasharray: 1px, 5px` (note the unit identifiers).

Comment: FYI - I opened a Chrome issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=832687#c1